# How can I make my iPhone App run both on 64 bit and 32 bit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

The exact error I get when I try to run in 64 bit mode, is `Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long'`.

I can fix this error by changing `%d` to `%ld`, however when I run the app in 32 bit (normal) mode, I get an error saying: `Format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int'`

How can I account for both 64 bit and 32 bit? Is there an if(condition) I create?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Handle the selection

    if(pickerView.tag == 1){
        start = row+1;
        [startButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@", row+1, [stops objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row+1]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else if (pickerView.tag == 2){
        stop = row+1;
        [endButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@", row+1, [stops objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row+1]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that long long and unsigned long long are both 64 bits on both 32 and 64 bit processors.

Comment: Won't a long long take up more space than a regular int? Is this practical for iPhones that only run 32 bits?

Comment: It will take 64 bits (8 bytes) but so what unless you have many thousands. Note this is not an answer, just info, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger` as format arguments. Instead cast them (for example to `long long`:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld", (long long)row+1]
```

Comment: What do I cast them to? How do I choose? Is long long the best choice?

Comment: `long long` is a safe choice. clang actually has a warning that recommends casting `NSInteger` to long.

Comment: If you don't need to cast to `long long`, you're probably fine just using `int` rather than `NSInteger` in the first place in this case.

Comment: One last question... Let's say I decided to keep my app working only for 32 bit, since it doesn't really need the bigger variable size of 64 bit... Will the new iPhone 5S downgrade to 32 bit for my app, or will it just not run the app?

Comment: A 64-bit app can handle `int` perfectly fine.  Using `int` rather than `NSInteger` doesn't downgrade the entire app to 32-bit...

Comment: The 5S can also run 32 bit apps, but why not just stick with code that works both on 32 and 64 bit architectures? Maybe a future iPhone won't run 32 bit apps.

Comment: won't a long long take up more space than a regular int? is this practical for iPhones without 64 bits?

Comment: Yes, to both questions.  But regardless, you're only CASTING it to a `(long long)` temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click `NSInteger`, and click "Go to definition", you can see exactly how it is `#define`d and use that as a skeleton to set up a similar `#define` for `%d`/`%ld` to match your `NSInteger`.

---

```
#if __LP64__
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

This is how `NSInteger` works.  You can do something similar:

```
#if __LP64__
#define FS_NSInt ld
#else
#define FS_NSInt d
#endif
```

Then just use `FS_NSInt` as your format specificer for `NSInteger`s.  (Put a `%` in front of it still)

Comment: So I should change `typedef int NSInteger;`?

Comment: No, you can't redefine a typedef in C.

Comment: Definitely not.  `NSInteger` is a conditional `typedef` that uses `int` on 32-bit systems and `long long` on 64-bit systems.  You can look at the `typedef` for `NSInteger` (I'm not on a Mac at the moment, or I'd write it for you) and use that as a skeleton to write a similiar condition `#define` for the format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004247-CH5-SW1):

Type Specifiers:

> Typically, in 32-bit code you use the %d specifier to format int
>   values in functions such > as printf, NSAssert, and NSLog, and in
>   methods such as stringWithFormat:. But with NSInteger, which on 64-bit
>   architectures is the same size as long, you need to use the %ld
>   specifier. Unless you are building 32-bit like 64-bit, these
>   specifiers generates compiler warnings in 32-bit mode. To avoid this
>   problem, you can cast the values to long or unsigned long, as
>   appropriate. For example:

```
NSInteger i = 34;
printf("%ld\n", (long)i);
```

One way around this is to use the types from stdint.h:
`int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t, int32_t, uint32_t, int64_t, uint64_t`

Comment: Won't casting a long, take up more space than an int? What if the iPhone is only 32 bit, then wouldn't it be better just to have an int? I'm a little confused, as this seems like a negative benefit... I was always thought to use the variable size that matched your need, a long is greater than my need. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you never need a number larger than what `int` will hold, you should just use `int` and not `NSInteger`.

Comment: Many of the older "truisms" are no longer really valid. Rule 1: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Story: I got a job because when asked about optimization I responded to measure first.

Comment: I guess the point I was trying to make is that the user is worried about wasting RAM on a 32-bit system by casting to a `long` but isn't worried about wasting the same RAM on a 64-bit system by using `NSInteger` (which will be a `long` on 64-bit).  If he's concerned and he doesn't need a number that `int` can't hold, he can just use `int` and avoid the issue in the original question all together.

Comment: Or he can just ignore the size/performance issue all together unless there are directly and demonstrated related performance issues.

Comment: In which case, he can just use a `long` instead of `NSInteger`.  Whether he goes with `long`, `long long`, or `int`, any option avoids the issues he's running into with `NSInteger`.  After all, `NSInteger` is an optimization `typedef`.